# Math and loop issue

Tags: javascript

I believe my input and sorting loop is correct although I'm unsure on the use of my brackets. New to java script so have lots of old java tendencies to break. Basically I want to take 3 inputs and figure out what's the largest, middle, and lowest number and if the two lower add to be greater than the largest or do not, to print the messages accordingly. Mainly just want to know what's wrong with my bracketing and my math statement. Getting errors on both my math and document.write statements. Thank you in advance.

```
 var x = prompt("Enter your first integer: ", x);

 var y = prompt("Enter your next integer: ", y);

 var z = prompt("Enter your last integer: ", z);

 var min = Number(min);
 var med = Number(med);
 var max = Number(max);

 if (x > y) {
     if (x > z) {
         max = x;
         if (y > z) {
             med = y;
             min = z;
         } else {
             med = z;
             min = y;
         }

     } else {
         med = x;
         if (y > z) {
             max = y;
             min = z;
         } else {
             max = z;
             min = y;
         }
     }
 } else {
     if (y > z) {
         max = y;
         if (x > z) {
             med = x;
             min = z;
         } else {
             med = z;
             min = x;
         }
     } else {
         med = y;
         max = z;
         min = x;
     }
 }

 var sum = min + med;
 if (sum > max) {
     document.write("The numbers ", x ", ", y "and, ", z ",satisfy the triangle    inequality");
      }else(sum < max){
     document.write("The numbers ", x ", ", y "and, ", z ",satisfy the triangle          inequality");
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: format the code nicely and it will be easy to see. http://jsbeautifier.org/.

Comment: `[x,y,z].sort(function(a,b){return a-b})`

Comment: mainly if the bracketing is correct and why I'm getting an error with my math and document.write statements.

Comment: There are many missing brackets and misalignment. It makes it very difficult to understand the logic of the code.

Comment: cleaned it up thank you @DLeh for the trip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the loop runs accurately, albeit with a duplicate entry (you've got two scenarios where it ends up z < x < y). Did you actually encounter any errors with this or did you just want us to check it before you ran it?

EDIT: wow, lots of activity while I wrote my answer haha! Anyways, the issue with the write statement is that you concatenate "These numbers " + X but you don't use a concatenate before ", " either time. Unless it assumes that but I don't believe it does. For the math portion, the only thing I can think of is that your else doesn't actually need the (min + med < max) because it's not an if statement. As an else it fires automatically when reached.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't gotten too far with running it. Still trying to kink out all of my syntax errors. Been back and forth between using the ", X" or "+ X" and it gives me syntax errors either way.

Comment: I think it'd work best if you did 
("The numbers " + x + ", " + y + ", and " + z + " satisfy the triangle inequality")

Comment: Ah forgot the plus sign after the variable. Thank you!

Comment: You're outputting the same statement regardless. Change the second statement to " do not satisfy the triangle inequality"

Comment: If this ended up helping you it's generally polite to mark it as the answer so that others can see it easier as well. Thanks!